# Where is this video of seaside cliffs filmed?

Tags: where-on-earth

[This is an advert](https://youtu.be/yeJjub3-8uk) (YouTube link) currently running on Japanese TV; the music sounds Irish and the scenery also feels like there, but where exactly? Google doesn't give me good results for this still:

[image: advert still]

Bonus prize if you can guess what it's advertising.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the [Cliffs of Moher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cliffs_of_Moher), County Clare, Ireland.